# The orthonormal basis $f_n(x) = e^{2\pi i nx}$ for $L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ defining Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I thought I understood this, but now I don't think I do.

So the functions $f_n(x) = e^{2 \pi i n x}$ form an orthonormal basis for the complex Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$.  This means for any square integrable function $f: \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb C$, I can find unique complex numbers $c_n \in \mathbb C$ such that

$$f = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n f_n$$
Formally, all this means is that the partial sums $F_N = \sum\limits_{n=-N}^N c_nf_n$ converge in the $L^2$ norm to $f$.

But if I take a random sequence $\{c_n\}$ of complex numbers, what is the sum

$$f:=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_nf_n?$$

It is supposed to be an element of $L^2(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$.  But $f$ does not appear to define a function $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb C$, or even an equivalence class of such functions (identifying those $f, g$ such that $||f-g||_2 = 0$).  After all, the sum $\sum\limits_n |c_n| |f_n| = \sum\limits_n |c_n|$ need not converge absolutely.

Comment: To nitpick, the usual definition of $f = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n f_n$ is _not_ that the partial sums from $-N$ to $N$ $L^2$-converge to $f$ but that the partial sums from $-M$ to $N$ $L^2$-converge to $f$ as $(M,N)\to\infty$.  It turns out to not make a difference in this case (as a consequence of the $f_n$ being orthonormal) but it does make a difference for more general sums.

Comment: What do you mean by "random sequence"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true that an *arbitrary* sequence $(c_n)$ represents an element of $L^2$.  Indeed, the only sequences that represent elements of $L^2$ are those for which $\sum c_nf_n$ actually *does* converge with respect to the $L^2$ norm to some function.  It turns out that this convergence is equivalent to the sum $\sum|c_n|^2$ converging.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I forgot that the Hilbert space direct sum is strictly smaller than the direct product.  So if $f$ is continuous, does $f(x)$ equal its Fourier series almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes but that is a deep theorem (much harder than the fact that its Fourier series converges to it in the $L^2$ norm).

Comment: Okay thank you.  One more question, does everything you said also hold for continuous functions and their Fourier expansions on the quotient $\mathbb A_k/k$?  Or more generally for the orthonormal basis of matrix coefficients on $L^2$ of a compact group via Peter-Weyl?

Comment: Everything I said in the answer applies to orthonormal bases for any Hilbert space.  I don't know anything about almost everywhere convergence for Fourier series on more general groups.